# Converting datetime to "passed time" till current time

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a date field in mysql that has datetime in the below period :

```
2014-05-31 15:00:55
```

I want to convert this value to "passed time" till current time.

for example if two hours are passed till the saved time,then I want something like this :

```
two hours ago
```

if three days are passed till the saved time,then it should be:

```
three days ago
```

I am trying to display the output with php as following :

```
<?php
echo '<p align="right">';
echo $row2['date'] ;
echo '</p>';
?>
```

I am new in PHP,Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108819/javascript-timestamp-to-relative-time-eg-2-seconds-ago-one-week-ago-etc-best ;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time

Comment: Try this URLS this might be helpful to you,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time][1]

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177836/how-to-format-time-since-xxx-e-g-4-minutes-ago-similar-to-stack-exchange-site][1]

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
function timeDiff(current, previous) {

    var msPerMin = 60 * 1000;
    var msPerHr = msPerMin * 60;
    var msPerDay = msPerHr * 24;
    var msPerMonth = msPerDay * 30;
    var msPerYear = msPerDay * 365;

    var elapsed = current - previous;

    if (elapsed < msPerMin) {
         return Math.round(elapsed / 1000) + ' seconds ago';   
    }

    else if (elapsed < msPerHr) {
         return Math.round(elapsed / msPerMin) + ' minutes ago';   
    }

    else if (elapsed < msPerDay ) {
         return Math.round(elapsed / msPerHr ) + ' hours ago';   
    }

    else if (elapsed < msPerMonth) {
        return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerDay) + ' days ago';   
    }

    else if (elapsed < msPerYear) {
        return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerMonth) + ' months ago';   
    }

    else {
        return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerYear ) + ' years ago';   
    }
}
```

Source: [Javascript timestamp to relative time (eg 2 seconds ago, one week ago etc), best methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108819/javascript-timestamp-to-relative-time-eg-2-seconds-ago-one-week-ago-etc-best/6109105#6109105)

---

This is how you implement it:

```
var now = new Date();
var someDate = new Date(2011, 04, 24, 12, 30, 00, 00);
alert(timeDiff(now, someDate));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DE78/).

Comment: Why didn't you just give the link to existing answer in comments instead of copy-pasting the code?

Comment: @chris97ong : I have edited my code. I am using php here.pls check