# How do i convert Youtube published date (ISO 8601) format in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, youtube

I'm using the YouTube Data API for loading videos, and the video upload date is returning in IOS-8601 format:

> 2015-04-07T03:00:03.000Z

how can convert in it into

> dd/mm/yyyy

or  display it into something like:

> yesterday or 4days ago;
>
> 2week ago;
>
> 1month ago;
>
> 1year ago;

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date("2015-04-07T03:00:03.000Z");
```

this should do the trick.
What you have is basically a JSON enconded string representation of a date. It includes the date offset as well and it will keep it once you translate it back into a date object,

Answer (score 0):

If your upload date was stored in variable `date`, you would do something like:

```
var date = new Date("2015-04-07T03:00:03.000Z");
var myDate = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

`getMonth()` returns integer from 0 to 11 hence `+1`

Please refer to [Javascript timestamp to relative time (eg 2 seconds ago, one week ago etc), best methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108819/javascript-timestamp-to-relative-time-eg-2-seconds-ago-one-week-ago-etc-best)
for "ago" format.