# ASP.NET MVC Date Time passed from Start

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm here to ask more how to do something rather than check my mistakes.

I have a value

```
public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

And I show it in the view like this:

```
asked @item.DateCreated by @item.Creator.FullName
```

which gives this

> asked 2/2/2018 2:28:13 PM by System Administrator

I would like to do it like in StackOverflow

> asked 5mins ago by x

What would your suggestions be for doing that? I'd need some code example, that's why I'm writing in SO, not SE.

Comment: Calculate it based on the value of `DateTime.Now` - e.g. `double duration = (DateTime.Now - DateCreated).TotalMinutes;` But you need to consider what happens when that's a large number - does it become `x hours and y minutes ago` or `x days` ago. And then you need to consider using a javascript timer to update it in the view (in the same way SO does it - e.g. the 'asked x mins ago' that you see above your name in this question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript timestamp to relative time (eg 2 seconds ago, one week ago etc), best methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108819/javascript-timestamp-to-relative-time-eg-2-seconds-ago-one-week-ago-etc-best)

Comment: Most people use JavaScript, the big advantage is that it does that it updates in "real time" in the browser. We're using [TimeAgo](http://timeago.yarp.com/) for that

Comment: @thmshd do I have to change the model though? because .NET uses a different standard for time?

Comment: No, you don't need to change the model if you want to use the JavaScript solution. You just need to convert the `DateCreated` value to a JavaScript date value. If you prefer to do it in C#, then you can use my answer, which also doesn't require changing your model if you don't want it.

Comment: I think I'll use the TimeAgo library. Makes things way easier. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
@{
    var diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateCreated);
    var result = diff.TotalSeconds;
    var unit = "seconds";
    if (result >= 60) {
        result = diff.TotalMinutes;
        unit = "minutes";

        if (result >= 60) {
            result = diff.TotalHours;
            unit = "hours";
        }
    }
}

asked @result @unit by @item.Creator.FullName
```

If you need to support more unites like `days`, then add more `if` blocks, but you get the idea.

You can put this code in code-behind and probably make the `result` and `unit` as properties of the `item` object.