# React Intl with relativeTime formatting

Tags: reactjs, intl

I'm working on a kind of dynamic timestamp for messages using `Intl`.

I want the timestamps to be dynamic in the way that it automatically transitions from ".. seconds ago" to "... minutes ago" to "... hours ago" to "today", after which it'll just return the date it's been posted. I know there's the `<RelativeFormat>` component, but I want to use the API instead.

The API has a method called `intl.relativeFormat`, but can't seem to figure out how to use it...

I'm a junior programmer so it's all still a bit new to me

I appreciate your time :)

If you need more info, please let me know. I'll try to provide you with more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Documentation for the RelativeFormat function can be found here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat.

The idea is that you create an instance of relative time format function, with some pre-defined settings that you want the output to follow. For example, you can set your relative time format function to return English strings in a shortened format.

```
 const rtf = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('en', { style: 'narrow' });

 console.log(rtf.format(3, 'quarters'));
 //expected output: "in 3 qtrs."
```

You also need to pass negative values in order to get labels intended for the past.

```
const rtf = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('en', { style: 'narrow' });

console.log(rtf.format(-3, 'quarters'));
//expected output: "3 qtrs. ago"
```

The next part leverages an answer given by @fearofawhackplanet [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108819/javascript-timestamp-to-relative-time)

```
//The 'timestamp' function parameter is your timestamp passed in milliseconds.
function timeDifference(timestamp, locale) {

    const msPerMinute = 60 * 1000;
    const msPerHour = msPerMinute * 60;
    const msPerDay = msPerHour * 24;
    const msPerMonth = msPerDay * 30;
    const msPerYear = msPerDay * 365;

    const current = Date.now();
    const elapsed = current - timestamp;

    const rtf = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat(locale, { numeric: "auto" });

    if (elapsed < msPerMinute) {
         return rtf.format(-Math.floor(elapsed/1000), 'seconds');   
    }

    else if (elapsed < msPerHour) {
         return rtf.format(-Math.floor(elapsed/msPerMinute), 'minutes'); 
    }

    else if (elapsed < msPerDay) {
         return rtf.format(-Math.floor(elapsed/msPerHour), 'hours');  
    }

    else {
        return new Date(timestamp).toLocaleDateString(locale);   
    }
}

//
// code to test the above function
//
const fifteenSecondsAgo = new Date();
const tenMinutesAgo = new Date();
const twoHoursAgo = new Date();

fifteenSecondsAgo.setSeconds(fifteenSecondsAgo.getSeconds() - 15);
tenMinutesAgo.setMinutes(tenMinutesAgo.getMinutes() - 10);
twoHoursAgo.setHours(twoHoursAgo.getHours() - 2);

console.log(timeDifference(fifteenSecondsAgo.getTime(), 'en'));
console.log(timeDifference(fifteenSecondsAgo.getTime(), 'es'));

console.log(timeDifference(tenMinutesAgo.getTime(), 'en'));
console.log(timeDifference(tenMinutesAgo.getTime(), 'es'));

console.log(timeDifference(twoHoursAgo.getTime(), 'en'));
console.log(timeDifference(twoHoursAgo.getTime(), 'es'));
```

Here is a JSFiddle link to see the code running - https://jsfiddle.net/mhzya237/1/

Comment: Hey Rusticus!
Thanks for your comment! I've figured it out tho.
The problem was the version of the plugins... We we're using an old one but managed to upgrade the package to a newer version. Doing this resulted in getting the expected outcome.

Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar idea, it also deals with future/present/past times.

```js
function getRelativeTime(time) {
  const now = new Date();
  const diff = Math.abs(time - now);
  const mark = (time - now) >> -1 || 1;

  if (diff === 0) return new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('en').format(0,"second");

  const times = [
    { type: 'second', seconds: 1000 },
    { type: 'minute', seconds: 60 * 1000 },
    { type: 'hour', seconds: 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    { type: 'day', seconds: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    { type: 'week', seconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    { type: 'month', seconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    { type: 'year', seconds: 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
  ];

  let params = [];
  for (let t of times) {
    const segment = Math.round(diff / t.seconds);
    if (segment >= 0 && segment < 10) {
      params = [(segment * mark) | 0, t.type];
      break;
    }
  }
  return new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('en').format(...params);
}

const time = getRelativeTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 2 * 1000));
console.info('relative time is', time);
```

The function takes a `time` param, finds the seconds difference relative to now, uses the array map to calculate which type yields the closest match and uses it as a param for `Intl.RelativeTimeFormat`

You can improve `getRelativeTime(time)` function by either returning the params array and call `Intl.RelativeTimeFormat` from outside the function or also pass the locale (and options) to the function.

I'm sure there are smarter ways to get rid of the `times` array, perhaps by creating a wrapping closure but it will force you to "initialize" this utility function first